# Can't access the values of nested list elements, Java 8

Tags: java, arraylist, netbeans, integer

First of all, I easily got this to work with the regular way of populating and accessing data from an array, so that as a suggested solution isn't what I'm looking for. I'm trying to better understand how to populate and access data from a multi-dimensional array. When I run the program the NetBeans error message is: `cannot find symbol`, `symbol: method get(int)`, `location: class Integer`. I've looked at the `.get()` method for `ArrayList` and to me it seems like I'm correctly trying to access that data but something isn't right. Also, on the last statement of the program code NetBeans says `incompatible types: ArrayList<Integer> cannot be converted to Object[]`. I'm guessing that's because when I'm trying print the values of each nested element each value wants to be accessed as a `String`, it's just a guess.

So the the array I want to populate should look like this: `[[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8], [9, 10, 11, 12]]`, and output should look something like below.

`1 2 3 4
5 6 7 8
9 10 11 12`

```
// TwoDimensionalArray_v2.java
// demonstrates populating and accessing elements from a two-dimensional array

package twodimensionalarray_v2;

import java.util.*;

public class TwoDimensionalArray_v2 {
  public static void main(String args[]) {
    // declare a dynamic array of class type Integer
    ArrayList<Integer> table = new ArrayList<>();

    // loop variables
    int i, j;

    // populate the array one nested element at a time
    for (i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
      for (j = 0; j < 4; ++j) {
        table.set(i, (i * 4) + j + 1);
        // >>>>> NetBeans error message is for the below line on .get(j) <<<<<
        System.out.print(table.get(i).get(j) + " ");
      }
      System.out.println();
    }

    // print 'table'
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(table));
  }
}
```

Comment: `table.get(i)` is of type `Integer` so no `get()` on it.

Comment: A 2-dim. List must be declared as `List<List<Integer>>`. USe `add` and `get` accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A list is a one-dimensional structure but you can use any aggregate for elements. Another List as element results in a two-dimensional array.

```
List<List<Integer>> table = new ArrayList<>();

// populate the array one nested element at a time
for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
  List<Integer> row;
  table.add( row = new ArrayList<Integer>() );
  for (int j = 0; j < 4; ++j) {
    row.add( (i * 4) + j + 1);
  }
}

for (int i = 0; i < table.size(); ++i) {
  for (int j = 0; j < table.get(i).size(); ++j) {
    System.out.print( " " + table.get(i).get(j));
  }
  System.out.println();
}
```

You could do the same using proper arrays.

Comment: "You could do the same using proper arrays." Yes, I stated in my post that I easily got this to work using the regular way. The point is to see if I could get it to work this way. Not all situations lend themselves to the regular way, like say a phone directory, or a list of vendors. My point is that sometimes data needs to be added and you won't know how much. To me, declaring a regular array with more overhead than you may need just adds needless overhead. I see my self educational task in this exercise as valid and with value even though the person that down voted me doesn't think so.

Answer (score 0):

your table is `Arraylist` ,

```
table.get(i)
```

will give you integer value that you had set at particulate position, as you are setting integer in array with line:

```
   table.set(i, (i * 4) + j + 1);
```

**so get(i) gives you integer value only not a array or list**

Answer (score -2):

Yep. sorry.
You cannot access get(j) because the List is just a list (one dimension).
You should use an primitive Array[][]

Comment: It will not change the type of `table.get(i)`.